# Prove that the equation$x^3 +3y^3 + 9z^3 = 9xyz$ has $x=y=z=0$ as its only rational solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x^3 +3y^3 + 9z^3 = 9xyz$ has 
$x=y=z=0$

I have seen the proof by contradiction that if it has a solution in rationals (integers specifically) with  at least 1 nonzero variable, it will have an infinite number number of integer solutions (by taking in and out factors of 3 on the original solution). I do not get why this result would lead to a contradiction. Why can't the equation have an infinite number of integer solutions.

Comment: $x$ must be divisible by $3$ Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent

Comment: Hello, i have seen that if $(x_0,y_0,z_0$ are solutions, then   $(x_0/3,y_0/3,z_0/3$  is also a solution, i have read in your article that it has to use something that is well ordered, but aren't rationals not well ordered?

Comment: Oops, I forgot that if it had a rational solution, then it had to be an integer solution. I'm not sure how the proof works, cant we just stop when x is not divisible by 3 anymore?

Answer (score 5):

Assume by contradiction this equation has a non-tivial ratonal solution.

Since the equation is homogeneous, we can multiply by the common denominator of $x,y,z$ to get a non-trivial integer solution.

Next we can divide by $gcd(x,y,z)$ to get a non-trivial integer solution with the propert $gcd(x,y,z)=1$.

Now, show that $3|x$, write $x=3x'$, then show that $3|y$, write $y=3y'$ and finally conclude that $3|z$. But this contradicts $gcd(x,y,z)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

As $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 =3abc\implies a+b+c=0\ or\ a=b=c.$

So $x=\sqrt[3]{3}y=\sqrt[3]{9}z$ cannot give rational roots (assume one of the them  rational other become irrational expect 0).

$x+\sqrt[3]{3}y+\sqrt[3]{9}z=0$ again cannot have rational roots expect 0 .(assume 2 rational 3rd becomes irrational)

Comment: Maybe add that the first implication follows immediately from the identity $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)$$ which is not to well known.

Answer (score 1):

My method is pretty much the same as the first solution posted with a different approach to the proof.

We can see that $3|x$. On writing $x=3x_1$ and cancelling the common factor, we get $3|y$. Write $y=3y_1$ and in the same way as before, we get $3|z$. Write $z=3z_1$

Now, we have circled back to $3|x_1$ so $x_1=3x_2$ or $x=3^{2}x_2$. We can do this process infinite times and the end result is that, our solution becomes $x=3^{n}x_n$ (we get similar solutions for $y$ and $z$) for arbitrarily large n. This is only possible when $x=0, y=0, z=0$.